# Opening .shp file under Add Vector Layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile

When I try to open streets.ship file from the exercise data file downloaded for working in the Quantum GIS Training Manual, I get an error message: Invalid Data Source C:/Users/new user/Documents/streets.ship is not a valid or recognized data source. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the extension is *.ship?  it should be *.shp

Comment: they are all in that folder but the error message seems to be hung up on the folder name. in addition the file names do not appear in the dialog box when i click on the filder name. the dialog is aslking for a folder not a file.

Comment: I have four shape files for my raster map that end with prefix below
.dbg
.aux
.sdw
sid
.sid.aux when i use the vector to load the map, it gives me this error message "raster_50kmaps.sdw is not a valid or recognized data source" Am I have having an incomplete shapefiles? how can i fix this problem?

Comment: @fatoma.momoh this seems to be a MrSID raster map, not a shapefile. Use `Add Raster Layer`, and select only the .sid file.

Answer (score 16):

A shapefile consists of (at least) three files. In your case *streets.shp*, *streets.dbf* and *streets.shx*. These files should al reside in the same folder. If one of them is missing, the error message "streets.shp is not a valid or recognized data source" will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure the zip file doesn't contain any "children" folders i.e. when you open the zip file you will have (at least three) the .shp, .dbf, .shx files with no parent folder above or below.