# Get Attributes from Shapefile in Geoserver as GeoJSON

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, geojson

I am working with QGIS and Geoserver. 
I have created a shapefile with an attribute table containing 4 rows/features and around 15 columns/attributes.

I published this file to Geoserver as Shapefile as points under publish section. I can see the four points in OpenLayer preview but when I select GeoJson from the dropdown I don't get the attribute table data.

Instead this is what I get.

```
    {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "totalFeatures": 4,
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "toilet_list_trial.1",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          72.840306,
          18.948056
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "the_geom",
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "toilet_list_trial.2",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          72.834778,
          18.947611
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "the_geom",
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "toilet_list_trial.3",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          72.834944,
          18.947861
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "the_geom",
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "toilet_list_trial.4",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          72.835278,
          18.947306
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "the_geom",
      "properties": {}
    }
  ],
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::404000"
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was me not copying rest of the files apart from the .shp file to the folder from where I was uploading data.

Once I copied other four files with extensions viz., .prj, .qpj, .shx and .dbf the attribute data now shows as it should.

[This is the link which made me realize my mistake](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70244/opening-shp-file-under-add-vector-layer)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what might be going wrong, if I goto

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=topp:states&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson
```

I get back the GeoJSON including all the attributes for the features as expected.

The only oddity in your data that I can see is that it has no projection set (it should be epsg:4326) but I doubt that could affect the attributes.

Comment: I just checked the SRS value. Its EPSG:404000. Can that be the problem? I'll try with 4326 and give update.

Comment: I set epsg:4326 from geoserver. it still doesn't show the attribute data.
Am I doing any mistake while saving the shapefile?

I just right click on layer and save it as shapefile with epsg:4326. Anything else I need to do?